# Powershell 4 Get-ChildItem doesn't recognize parameter DnsName, Cert:\LocalMachine\My works fine

Tags: powershell, named-parameters, get-childitem

What am I doing wrong? All the web says "to look in the Certificate provider to find certs with this dns name, use command `Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "Will we ever know?"` and lo and behold, it ACTUALLY WORKS on most of my machines. Also of note, `Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My` happily returns certs, it's specifically the filter at fault.

> see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847761.aspx

But for some subclass of machines in my environment (I have a lot of machines to manage, hence the automation via powershell), I get this:

```
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DnsName'.
At line:1 char:43
+ Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "what does the fox say" ...
+                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Note that I have anonymized certain facets, so this query "as written" won't work, because internal details don't matter. Why am I getting the `NamedParameterNotFound` on this query?

Notes:

- Server 2008 R2
- .NET 4.5.1 installed (before today)
- Powershell v4
  installed (today)

Comment: by "certain facets" I mean the references to "what does the fox say"

Comment: Is it possible on those machines the [cert provider is not loaded](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847807.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry, meant to comment this: I do indeed get results for all certs loaded in  LocalMachine\My when I leave off the search on the DnsName parameter. Let me update the post.

Comment: Someone else suggests that `gci -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select DnsNameList` also returning empty on the machine could indicate that appropriate certs are not loaded, so therefore there is nothing to filter on this machine, and that is the cause of the filter (that's a bad design, imo, but I can live with that)

Comment: Are you accessing the other machines remotely from your session in PowerShell v4 on that server? Before PSv4 the Cert provider was not automatically loaded into every session, so running Get-ChildItem against the cert: drive would not return any results if you ran that command on another computer with an older version of powershell.

Comment: No, this is going on the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reminded that I never answered this question with what worked. Apparently we most likely installed an update. I'm torn between deleting this question or just saying we installed the latest tool we needed since this is for Server 2008.

If you are finding this because you're having this issue with 2008, comment below and I'll try to help you so we can close this issue properly!

Answer (score 1):

Check `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`: option `-DnsName` was introduced in PowerShell 3.0

Check if you have drive mapped `Get-PSDrive -Name 'Cert'` and provider "*Cerificate*" using `Get-PSProvider`

Force to map another Cert drive using

`New-PSDrive -PSProvider Certificate -Name 'Cert2' -Root '\'`

Comment: Did you miss where we force installed PS4 before coming here? I'll check the others. ...